# Remove www but do not affect subdomain (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, canonical-link

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This strips www from the URL.

Without the rule the subdomain works (blog.site.com). With the rule it converts back to (site.com/blog) and shows 404 errors.

**What do I need to do to keep this from affecting the subdomain(s)?**

*Also, I'm curious if removing the www. is a good thing? I've heard it doesn't matter as long as you pick one and stick to it. I'm also using `<link rel="canonical" ... />` to re-enforce it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `(blog\.)?` at the begin blog. becomes optional and so it will redirect only if it is different from `blog.mysite.com` and `mysite.com`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(blog\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

A different way to do the same would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which means if hostname is different then `mysite.com` and `blog.mysite.com` redirect.

To avoid duplicity it is good to choose between www or non-www and redirect every thing for that.

So if u use www then redirect non-www to www and vice versa.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Was missing the `\ ` and `?` in what I tried.

Comment: The `?` makes the previous group or character optional so it match one or another :) pretty handy.